# Is there any technical reason that the android documentation tells you to use lifecycle-aware components rather than callbacks?

Tags: android

In the android developer documentation, it says:

> Some actions belong in the activity lifecycle methods. However, place code that implements the actions of a dependent component in the component, rather than the activity lifecycle method. To achieve this, you need to make the dependent component lifecycle-aware

I am wondering is there any technical requirement for this, or is it just an architectural best practice? I would have thought that whether you use an activity lifecycle callback or a callback in your dependent component, both of these will be called from the main thread, with the risk of holding up the main thread if they take too long. So it doesn't really matter whether a short piece of processing is in the activity lifecycle method or one in a dependent component. Or is there some technical problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Lifecycle aware component]:(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

> Lifecycle-aware components perform actions in response to a change in the lifecycle status of another component, such as activities and fragments. These components help you produce better-organized, and often lighter-weight code, that is easier to maintain.

> A common pattern is to implement the actions of the dependent components in the lifecycle methods of activities and fragments. However, this pattern leads to a poor organization of the code and to the proliferation of errors. By using lifecycle-aware components, you can move the code of dependent components out of the lifecycle methods and into the components themselves.

Yes, from the perspective of thread, performance, and functionality for app users. We can implement the same function or performance whether using or not using lifecycle-aware components. It is just an architectural best practice. So the difference lies in how much effort is spent by developers to implement the same things.

For apps with simple business logic, there is no need to consider much about architecture. It doesn't really matter whether a short piece of processing is in the activity lifecycle method or one in a dependent component.

But for some large apps with complicated business logic, good architecture really matters. For example, with lifecycle-aware components, different business logic components can be easily better-organized, decoupled, and independent of activity/fragment, which decreases the code of activity/fragment and makes your project much more readable and better maintainability and testability. Also, the components will be easier to be reused.

There is a good [tutorial](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/android-life-cycle-aware-components/) which can help to easily understand.